# Javascript href leaving url on page

Tags: javascript

I am working on an older system where the top menu is housed in a frame. I know, bad practice, but as I said, it is an old system. The tabbed menu used javascript to change pages like this:

```
<a href="javascript:top.location.href='/content/newpage'">Link</a>
```

This works, but the page is a complex page and takes a while to load and while it is loading, I get /content/newpage displayed in that top frame. This only happens in Chrome 29 as far as I know. It does not happen in Firefox or IE or previous versions of Chrome.

Is there a way around this? Can I use the target parameter to force to top frame and thus, use 'regular' links rather than javascript?

Comment: I have considered using jquery to trap the tab clicks and then immediately collapse the frame, but that seems like such a kludge.

Comment: What about `Window.open()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="top.location.href='/content/newpage'; return false">Link</a>
```

Comment: This worked. I also used target="_parent" and that worked as well.